# DatePicker in xaml.vb

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am completely new to XAML.vb. when I want to calculate the age in .cs, I used to enter the following code:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_valueChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DateTime from = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime  to = dateTimePicker1.Now;
TimeSpan Tspan = to-from;
double days = Tspan.TotalDays;
textbox1.Text = (days/365)ToString("0");
}
```

The following code is from XAML.VB. All the functions that I used in cs before are not present.

```
Private Sub dob_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

{

DateTime from = dob.Value;  // it doesn't exist. I found dob.GetValue but its not helping.

}
```

Same was with "TimeSpan" and all the other built-in functions from Microsoft they have changed it so much and much is not available on the internet. It would be great if someone has any idea about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`DateTimePicker` is a WindowsForms control. In WPF the control is called `DatePicker` and it has a `SelectedDate` property that returns a `Nullable(Of DateTime)`.

Try this.

**XAML:**

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dob" SelectedDateChanged="dob_SelectedDateChanged" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
```

**VB.NET:**

```
Private Sub dob_SelectedDateChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    Dim fromDate = dob.SelectedDate.Value
    Dim toDate = DateTime.Now
    Dim tspan = toDate - fromDate
    Dim days = tspan.TotalDays
    textBox1.Text = days.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Timespan is available in vb too... check on this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Follwoing is the same code in vb ....

```
Private Sub dateTimePicker1_valueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim from As DateTime = dateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim [to] As DateTime = dateTimePicker1.Now
    Dim Tspan As TimeSpan = [to] - from
    Dim days As Double = Tspan.TotalDays
    textbox1.Text = (days / 365).ToString("0")
End Sub
```